# Web view for moodle app after npm start command not working properly?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, moodle, moodle-mobile

I have followed every steps as mentioned [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2)

And then i ran the `npm start` command and also `ionic serve` command separately, but command prompt does not show any errors nor the browser console, web browser showing this,

[image]
'

command prompt

[image]

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on Windows? There is an issue where `npm start` hangs. If you run the npx commands directly yourself, it works. See the [Troubleshooting entry in the documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2#Windows:_npm_start.0A_hangs_after_.22Starting_.27watch.27.22).

Comment: Yes i'm using Windows, but npm start command running without a any errors

Comment: It may not be giving you an error, but that doesn't mean it's running to completion. As the link says, it can hang on "Starting 'watch'". Did you try running the commands shown at that link?